# Match a particular letter and print word after that using SED

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file "Log.txt" which look like this:

```
 bla bla.. line1   
 bla bla.. line2  
 bla bla.. lineN     
:000000 ... 239e670... A  bla1.txt  
:000000 ... 76fd777... M  bla2.txt  
:000000 ... e69de29... A  bla3.txt
```

Let's say that I am looking for the letter 'A' and 'M'.

How would I look for it ONLY in the 4th field or line that contains this particular letter only. I need to Match the words "A" and "M" only and print the file name after that. i.e I need to get final output as below:

```
A   bla1.txt
M   bla2.txt
A   bla3.txt
```

I used awk to match 4th column with A and M and print the next word. but not getting the expected output. I'm getting extra Bla Bla lines also.

Anyone has idea how to achieve this using sed?

Comment: Does your 'A' or 'M' appear only in the 4th field or it can appear anywhere in the line?

Comment: @user123  Yes in actual file 'A' or 'M' appears in 4th field. but it should not match with any other word contains A or M ( i.e, RAJESH, which has A in it)

Comment: To get help debugging your code, you have to show us your code. Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` for this:

```
awk '$4 ~ /^[AM]$/ { print $4," ",$5 }' Log.txt
```

`sed` for it:

```
sed -En '/^([^ ]+ ){3}[AM]/ { s/^([^ ]+ ){3}([AM] .*)/\2/; p; }' Log.txt
```

Both of these confirm that the `A` or `M` is in the 4th field.

Answer (score 0):

Awk actually can do your job, just need to add a condition:

```
awk "/ (A|M) /{print $4,$5}" Log.txt
```

As for sed, you can do this:

```
sed -nr "/ (A|M) /{s/.*((A|M)\s+.*)$/\1/;p}" Log.txt
```

Not sure how are your real data looks like, but I guess you will get it and adjust the command to suit them.

Answer (score 0):

As per your input file and your expected output, Please try below using `awk`:

```
awk '{if ($4 == "A" || $4 == "M") {print $4,$5}}' log.txt
```

Output:

```
A bla1.txt
M bla2.txt
A bla3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\(\S*\s\)\{3\}\([AM]\s\)/\2/p;d' file
```

Match the fourth field to be `A` or `M` and if so, remove the first three fields and print the remainder.